# Getting error "Google Play services is not available. This application will close" on Android device having Android version 4.1.2

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to Android programming world.
I was trying to create a G+ login using documentation at https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/samples/quickstart-android.
(I did that using android studio)

I am successfully able to log in and log out on my Moto-G (Android version 5.0.2). However, I'm unable to do the same with Samsung Galaxy Trend (Android version 4.1.2). The error that I'm getting here is: "**Google Play services is not available. This application will close.**"

I have not done anything apart from what is mentioned in the documentation.
Can somebody please guide me on what is going wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It happens me when my android was not updated here is the code that check, i used 2 years ago

```
**
     * Verify that Google Play services is available before making a request.
     *
     * @return true if Google Play services is available, otherwise false
     */
    private boolean servicesConnected() {

        // Check that Google Play services is available
        int resultCode =
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getActivity());

        // If Google Play services is available
        if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == resultCode) {
            // In debug mode, log the status
            //Log.d(LocationUtils.APPTAG, getString(R.string.play_services_available));

            // Continue
            return true;
            // Google Play services was not available for some reason
        } else {
            // Display an error dialog
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, getActivity(), 0);
            if (dialog != null) {
                ErrorDialogFragment errorFragment = new ErrorDialogFragment();
                errorFragment.setDialog(dialog);
                errorFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "Baja Wanted");
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Show a dialog returned by Google Play services for the
     * connection error code
     *
     * @param errorCode An error code returned from onConnectionFailed
     */
    private void showErrorDialog(int errorCode) {

        // Get the error dialog from Google Play services
        Dialog errorDialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(
                errorCode,
                getActivity(),
                CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);

        // If Google Play services can provide an error dialog
        if (errorDialog != null) {

            // Create a new DialogFragment in which to show the error dialog
            ErrorDialogFragment errorFragment = new ErrorDialogFragment();

            // Set the dialog in the DialogFragment
            errorFragment.setDialog(errorDialog);

            // Show the error dialog in the DialogFragment
            errorFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "Baja Wanted");
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Define a DialogFragment to display the error dialog generated in
 * showErrorDialog.
 */
public static class ErrorDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    // Global field to contain the error dialog
    private Dialog mDialog;

    /**
     * Default constructor. Sets the dialog field to null
     */
    public ErrorDialogFragment() {
        super();
        mDialog = null;
    }

    /**
     * Set the dialog to display
     *
     * @param dialog An error dialog
     */
    public void setDialog(Dialog dialog) {
        mDialog = dialog;
    }

    /*
     * This method must return a Dialog to the DialogFragment.
     */
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return mDialog;
    }
}
```

}

Google Play Services util

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil